# make recent log agg with unix timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm making a webpage user access log table in BigQuery.
But I don't know how agg log with exit_time.
I want recent 5 view page log array. 
If view page log is less than 5, the array is shorter. 
plz teach me.

```
USER_EXIT_LOG AS (
SELECT 
    ['A','A','B'] AS user_id,
    [1000,2000,1000] AS exit_time
),

VIEW_PAGE_LOG AS (
SELECT 
    ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B'] AS user_id,
    ['a','b','c','d','e','a','b'] AS view_page_id,
    [800,900,1800,1900,1950,800,900] AS time

)

USER_EXIT_LOG
| user_id  | exit_time |
| -------- | --------- |
| A        | 1000      |
| A        | 2000      |
| B        | 1000      |

VIEW_PAGE_LOG
| user_id  | view_page_id | view_time |
| -------- | -----------  | --------- |
| A        | a            | 800       |
| A        | b            | 900       |
| A        | c            | 1800      |
| A        | d            | 1900      |
| B        | a            | 800       |
| B        | b            | 900       |

WHAT I WANT
| user_id | exit_time | view_page_array |
| ------- | --------- | --------------- |
| A       | 1000      | [b,a]           |
| A       | 2000      | [e,d,c]         |
| B       | 1000      | [b,a]           |
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Your sample data shows rows but the definitions show arrays.  I don't even understand what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select u.user_id, exit_time, 
  array_agg(view_page_id order by view_time desc limit 5) as view_page_array 
from (
  select user_id, exit_time,
    ifnull(lag(exit_time + 1) over(partition by user_id order by exit_time), 0) start_time
  from `project.dataset.USER_EXIT_LOG`
) u
join `project.dataset.VIEW_PAGE_LOG` v 
on u.user_id = v.user_id
and view_time between start_time and exit_time
group by user_id, exit_time
```

If applied t sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.USER_EXIT_LOG` as (
  select 'A' user_id, 1000 exit_time union all
  select 'A', 2000 union all
  select 'B', 1000 
), `project.dataset.VIEW_PAGE_LOG` as (
  select 'A' user_id, 'a' view_page_id, 800 view_time union all
  select 'A', 'b', 900 union all
  select 'A', 'c', 1800 union all
  select 'A', 'd', 1900 union all
  select 'A', 'e', 1950 union all
  select 'B', 'a', 800 union all
  select 'B', 'b', 900 
)
```

the output is

[image]